# Python decorator to determine order of execution of methods

Tags: python, decorator

I have a basic class `Framework` with 3 methods that can be set by the user: `initialize`, `handle_event` and `finalize`.

These methods are executed by the method `run`:

```
class Framework(object):

    def initialize(self):
        pass

    def handle_event(self, event):
        pass

    def finalize(self):
        pass 

    def run(self):
        self.initialize()

        for event in range(10):
            self.handle_event(event)

        self.finalize()
```

I would like to create 3 decorators: `on_initialize`, `on_event` and `on_finalize` so that I could write such a class:

```
class MyFramework(Framework):

    # The following methods will be executed once in this order
    @on_initialize(precedence=-1)
    def say_hi(self):
        print('say_hi')

    @on_initialize(precedence=0)
    def initialize(self):
        print('initialize')

    @on_initialize(precedence=1)
    def start_processing_events(self):
        print('start_processing_events')

    # The following methods will be executed in each event in this order
    @on_event(precedence=-1)
    def before_handle_event(self, event):
        print('before_handle_event:', event)

    @on_event(precedence=0)
    def handle_event(self, event):
        print('handle_event:', event)

    @on_event(precedence=1)
    def after_handle_event(self, event):
        print('after_handle_event:', event)

    # The following methods will be executed once at the end on this order
    @on_finalize(precedence=-1)
    def before_finalize(self):
        print('before_finalize')

    @on_finalize(precedence=0)
    def finalize(self):
        print('finalize')

    @on_finalize(precedence=1)
    def after_finalize(self):
        print('after_finalize')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = MyFramework()
    f.run()
```

These decorators determine the order of execution of the optional methods the user may add to the class. I think that by default, `initialize`, `handle_event` and `finalize` should take `precedence=0`. Then the user could add any method with the right decorator and he will know when they get executed in the simulation run.

I have honestly no idea how to get started with this problem. Any help to push me in the right direction will be very welcome! Many thanks.

Comment: Your `Framework` class could have lists for `on_initialize` and the other two, and those decorators could add those function to those lists and then return the functions unchanged.

Comment: But why not just overwrite those methods in the sub-class? Would be much cleaner IMHO. Any specific use case that can not be handled that way?

Comment: But that idea (with the lists) would require the decorators to "know" which class' lists to add those functions to... not sure if/how that's possible.

Comment: It could be done with a metaclass. The decorators could 'mark' the functions and the metaclass would then collect all marked methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.6, this is a case that can take advantage of the new `__init_subclass__` method. It is called on the superclass by subclasses when they are created.

Withut Python3.6 you have to resort to a metaclass.

The decorator itself can just mark each method with the needed data.

```
def on_initialize(precedence=0):
    def marker(func):
        func._initializer = precedence
        return func
    return marker

def on_event(precedence=0):
    def marker(func):
        func._event_handler = precedence
        return func
    return marker


def on_finalize(precedence=0):
    def marker(func):
        func._finalizer = precedence
        return func
    return marker



class Framework:

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)
        handlers = dict(_initializer=[], _event_handler=[], _finalizer=[])
        for name, method in cls.__dict__.items():
            for handler_type in handlers:
                if hasattr(method, handler_type):
                    handlers[handler_type].append((getattr(method, handler_type), name))

        for handler_type in handlers:
            setattr(cls, handler_type, 
                    [handler[1] for handler in sorted(handlers[handler_type])])

    def initialize(self):
        for method_name in self._initializer:
            getattr(self, method_name)()

    def handle_event(self, event):
        for method_name in self._event_handler:
            getattr(self, method_name)(event)

    def finalize(self):
        for method_name in self._finalizer:
            getattr(self, method_name)()

    def run(self):
        self.initialize()

        for event in range(10):
            self.handle_event(event)

        self.finalize()
```

If you will have a complex class hierarchy that should inherit the action methods properly, you wll have to merge the lists in the `handlers` dictionary with the ones in the superclass (get the superclass as `cls.__mro__[1]`) before applying then as class attributes.

Also, if you are using any Python < 3.6, you will need to move the logic on `__init_subclass__` to a metaclass. Just put the code as it is on the `__init__` method of a metaclass (and adjust the incoming parameters and super call as apropriate), and it should work just the same.

Comment: Should'nt your `on_event` etc. decorator functions be the other way around and return something?

Comment: yes . I was thinking of making a small factory for them, then I just gave up, but did not change the draft. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting this error while trying to run your code: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'handler_type' referenced before assignment. Any idea what's wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi there, it solved my problem. Many thanks for you help!

Comment: yep - it looks like I dropped a line in the code as matters of editing on the form here. Fixing it now - it was lacking a second `for` loop for the handler types when checking for the class attributes.

Comment: @jsbueno, can you explain how you would handle a case with multiple inheritance? For example, I have a class Recorder(Framework) that has a special method record(self) that needs to be passed to _finalizer. And my other class MyFramework(Recorder) that does some other things. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use class based decorators, which are simple and gives intermediate context to share between decorated functions. So decorator would look like this (I am using python3.5):

```
class OnInitialize:
  methods = {}

  def __init__(self, precedence):
    self.precedence = precedence

  def __call__(self, func):
    self.methods[self.precedence] = func
    def wrapper(*a, **kw):
      for precedence in sorted(self.methods.keys()):
        self.methods[precedence](*a, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

on decoration, first of all **init** is executed and it stores the precedence value for further use. Secondly the **call** is executed which just appends target function to the methods dictionary (Please note that **call** and methods structure could be customized to allow calling multiple methods with same precedence).

on the other hand, target class and methods would look like this

```
class Target:
  @OnInitialize(precedence=-1)
  def say_hi(self):
    print("say_hi")

  @OnInitialize(precedence=0)
  def initialize(self):
    print("initialize")

  @OnInitialize(precedence=1)
  def start_processing_events(self):
    print("start_processing_events")
```

which ensures that, if one of the following methods are called, it will call all the decorated methods with given order.

```
target = Target()
target.initialize()
```

Hope it helps, please comment me below if you were interested in something other.

Comment: This is somewhat ingenous, but is not "ready for consunption". Methods with equal precedence would override each other - that is fixable by uisng a list in your dictionary. You use a class-wide dictionary: that would mix all methods on the OP's class hierarchy together. You need one such icionary for each class the operators are used on. And each of the methods decorated is kept visible and existing on the class, but all of them would execute the full action of all methods upon being called.