# Inheritance with decorators

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator, python-decorators

This question is an extension of a previous question I posted here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054796/python-decorator-to-determine-order-of-execution-of-methods)

I use Python 3.6.2. I have a generic class `Framework` from which my systems inherit.

I use the decorators `on_initialize`, `on_event`, and `on_finalize` to inform the `Framework` where each method must be executed. The argument `precedence` of each decorator is used to determine the order of execution for each section (from lower to higher).

```
# 3 decorators 
def on_initialize(precedence=0):
    def marker(func):
        func._initializer = precedence
        return func
    return marker


def on_event(precedence=0):
    def marker(func):
        func._event_handler = precedence
        return func
    return marker


def on_finalize(precedence=0):
    def marker(func):
        func._finalizer = precedence
        return func
    return marker

# Main framework
class Framework:

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)
        handlers = dict(_initializer=[], _event_handler=[], _finalizer=[])
        for name, method in cls.__dict__.items():
            for handler_type in handlers:
                if hasattr(method, handler_type):
                    handlers[handler_type].append((getattr(method, handler_type), name))

        for handler_type in handlers:
            setattr(cls, handler_type, 
                    [handler[1] for handler in sorted(handlers[handler_type])])

    def _initialize(self):
        for method_name in self._initializer:
            getattr(self, method_name)()

    def _handle_event(self, event):
        for method_name in self._event_handler:
            getattr(self, method_name)(event)

    def _finalize(self):
        for method_name in self._finalizer:
            getattr(self, method_name)()

    def run(self):
        self._initialize()

        for event in range(10):
            self._handle_event(event)

        self._finalize()


class Recorder(Framework):

    @on_finalize(precedence=0)
    def save_to_db(self):
        print('save_to_db')


class TestFramework(Recorder):

    @on_initialize(precedence=0)
    def get_data(self):
        print('get_data')

    @on_initialize(precedence=1)
    def prepare_data(self):
        print('prepare_data')

    @on_event(precedence=0)
    def process_event(self, event):
        print('process_event', event)

    @on_finalize(precedence=1)
    def generate_report(self):
        print('generate_report')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf = TestFramework()
    tf.run()
```

The results:

```
> get_data 
> prepare_data 
> process_event 0 
> process_event 1 
> process_event 2
> process_event 3 
> process_event 4 
> process_event 5 
> process_event 6
> process_event 7 
> process_event 8 
> process_event 9 
> generate_report
```

The method `save_to_db` from `Recorder` is not executed in `TestFramework`. I think I'm missing something in `__init_subclass__` where I should be iterating through each subclass. Any idea? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set a new set of handlers *per class*, ignoring those of any base class.

Rather than use empty lists in the `handlers` dictionary, look for existing lists and start with those:

```
def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
    super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)
    handlers = dict(
        _initializer=getattr(cls, '_initializer', []),
        _event_handler=getattr(cls, '_event_handler', []),
        _finalizer=getattr(cls, '_finalizer', [])))
    # ...
```

You do then have to eliminate any methods that the subclass has overridden!

Alternatively, rather than use only the current class namespace (via `cls.__dict__`), use the combined names available in `dir()`:

```
def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
    super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)
    handlers = dict(_initializer=[], _event_handler=[], _finalizer=[])
    for name in dir(cls):
        method = getattr(cls, name)
        for handler_type in handlers:
            if hasattr(method, handler_type):
                handlers[handler_type].append((getattr(method, handler_type), name))
```